# How can we reset or empty layout in android

Tags: android

Hi I am working on an application which creates dynamic components like buttons etc.
When a certain condition occurs, I want to remove or empty my layout..  Can anyone guide or suggest me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the function **removeAllViews()** on your layout.

Answer (score 3):

All of the Layout classes are children of ViewGroup so you can use the [ViewGroup.removeAllViews()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeAllViews%28%29) method

Answer (score 0):

**`yourLayout.removeAllViews();`** should work fine....